# C++ SFINAE - difference of std::enable_if position - in template or in return

Tags: c++, sfinae

What is the difference of these two implementations and which of them should I use, since whey both work the same if I call them from main:

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void test( const T& t ){
    printf("int\n");
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void test( const T& t ){
        printf("float\n");
}
```

vs

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type test1( const T& t ){
    printf("int\n");
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type test1( const T& t ){
    printf("float\n");
}
```

and the main:

```
int main(){ 
   test(1);
   test(1.0); 

   test1(1);
   test1(1.0); 
}
```

Comment: No real difference in this case. Use whatever you like the most.

Comment: The second form is compatible pre-C++11. The first one is usable for constructor and has simpler function signature (in case you want to create function pointer).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ho yeah! right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default second argument of `std::enable_if` is `void`, so that the expression `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type = 0` is ill formed.

---

The case with `enable_if` for the return value does not introduce an unnecessary template argument with an initializer and therefore is more elegant and less error-prone for function templates.

As you have noticed, it is easier to make a mistake when introducing that unnecessary template argument.

Class templates, on the other hand, must use the extra template argument for SFINAE, since there is no return value.

Comment: I am sorry, I had an typo in that

Comment: I'd prefer an answer saying both are legal and behave similarly (this answers the question), the choice between the two being a simple preference, yours being the later because reasons (that let you give your opinion).

Comment: For the first sample, If i change signature to: `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr`, I can use `void` in second `enable_if` argument